# Tab Widget not displaying correctly onResume()

Tags: android, layoutparams, android-windowmanager, clipped

I'm using a custom TabWidget to display my tabs.  The tabs work wonderfully when I first run the program.  Everything looks beautiful.  However, when I reload the program and, according the logcat, the onResume() method is called on my Tab Widget, the TabWidget displays only the top half of the widget. Here is the XML for my TabWidget.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_above="@android:id/tabs"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

It's pretty plain vanilla stuff here.  Changing the layout_height doesn't help.

I am currently not implementing onResume in my TabWidget.java. But heres the code anyway.

```
public class TabWidget extends TabActivity {

    private TabHost mTabHost;

    private void setupTabHost() {
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); // The
                                                                        // activity
                                                                        // TabHost

        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

        setupTabHost();
        // mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

        // Dealer tab
        Intent intentDealer = new Intent().setClass(this, DealerActivity.class);
        int iconDealer = (R.drawable.ic_tab_dealer);
        setupTab("Dealer", intentDealer, iconDealer);

        // Department tab
        Intent intentDept = new Intent().setClass(this, DeptActivity.class);
        int iconDept = R.drawable.ic_tab_dept;
        setupTab("Departments", intentDept, iconDept);

        // PostBoard Activity
        Intent intentBoard = new Intent().setClass(this, BoardActivity.class);
        int iconBoard = R.drawable.ic_tab_board;
        setupTab("Postboard", intentBoard, iconBoard);

        // Social Network connection
        // Check first to see if there are Social Network links if not don't
        // show tab.
        if (Startup.msMain.locations[Startup.nChosenLocation].social_media_feeds.length == 0) {

        } else {
            Intent intentSocial = new Intent().setClass(this,
                    SocialActivity.class);
            int iconSocial = R.drawable.ic_tab_social;
            setupTab("Social Media", intentSocial, iconSocial);
        }

        // Links Activity
        Intent intentLinks = new Intent().setClass(this, LinksActivity.class);
        int iconLinks = R.drawable.ic_tab_link;
        setupTab("Links", intentLinks, iconLinks);

        // set startup tab
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }

    private void setupTab(final String tag, Intent intent, int img) {
        View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag, img);

        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview)
                .setContent(intent);

        mTabHost.addTab(setContent);

    }

    private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text,
            int img) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                .inflate(R.layout.tabs_bg, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
        tv.setText(text);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsIcon);
        icon.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(img));
        return view;
    }
}
```

And for thoroughness here's my logcat when the error appears.

```
   12-28 10:10:00.963: I/ActivityManager(1305): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.zocalolabs.demo/.SplashScreen } from pid 1470
   12-28 10:10:01.034: W/InputManagerService(1305): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40777988 (uid=10001 pid=1470)
   12-28 10:10:01.073: I/ActivityManager(1305): Resumed Activity: com.zocalolabs.demo/.TabWidget totalTime: 110 ms
```

Is there a way to force my widget activity to redraw on onResume() or onPause() force it to full on kill the Activity thus forcing it to the onCreate method again?  Or is there another way to attack this problem?  Thanks for any insights!

Comment: So I suppose I don't get points for answering my own question but it turned out the culprit was

Comment: actually, if you do find the answer to your own problem, it's good practice to answer your own question and then select it as the right answer. Don't be shy about that! That way, if someone does find your question/answer helpful they can up vote you and give you credit. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: Thanks.  I went ahead and moved it down to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that

```
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

was clipping the bottom of the activity view. I don't know if this is a bug or what but the fix was to add the following line.

```
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Hope this helps someone else.